# How to get a key for a combination of 3 objects in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, key-value

I have the following class:

```
public class foo extends Pair<String, String> {
    private foo(String flag, String id) {
        super(flag, id);
    }

    public static foo of(String flag, String id) {
        return new foo(flag, id);
    }
}
```

How can I repeat the above if I have 3 parameters to be used as a combination as a key instead of just 2: `String flag, String id and MyObject myobject`?

The `MyObject` is something like this:

```
public interface MyObject {
    String valueOf();
}
```

Which data structure can I use for the "extends" part instead of `Pair<String,String>` to accommodate all 3 parameters mentioned above?

Comment: Why are you using `Pair` at all?  Just make a perfectly normal class with `equals`, `toString`, `hashCode`, and getters.

Comment: You need just a POJO I think.

Comment: ```Pair``` is used since we want a combination of flag and id as a key. This is a part of code that is already given to me, I was unsure on how to scale this to use 3 parameters as a key. I'm also new to Java, so any code implementation examples would be helpful.

Comment: As we said, you can use a normal class for your keys so that you can add as many as you want.

Comment: You can also use List<String>

Answer (score 0):

If you never want to modify a value inside `foo` after creation ("immutable") and use Java 14 or newer, you can simply create a `record` (and please name it with an uppercase letter in the beginning for classes and records and enums).

If you need the `of` method, you can also add that to a record as you would do it for a class.

```java
public record Foo (String flag, String id, String third) {
  public Foo of(String flag, String id, String third) {
    return new Foo(flag, id, third);
  } 
}
```

"Downside": it doesn't have a private constructor, so the `of` method is quite useless probably - but it's the same as for the implementation you showed.

A `record` will automatically have the fields, a constructor with parameters to initialize the fields, proper implementation of `equals` and `hashcode` that takes all of the fields into account and a `toString` method that prints the values of the fields.

Oh, not to forget also a getter method for each field.